# Display files in a folder to a CSV using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csv

Is there a simple way to display the files in a folder to a CSV that shows whether the files in that folder are JPG, PDF, or other using C#?

Comment: You don't need C# - just run `dir /b > files.tsv` from your command-line.

Comment: csv file is created in the folder.
     string path = filePath + "\\" + time+ ".csv";
     string temp = string.Format("{0},{1}", 111111, 22222);
     StreamWriter swrite = new StreamWriter(path, true, Encoding.UTF8);
     swrite.Write(temp);

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do this in C#, but you can use the `System.IO.Directory` and `System.IO.File` classes to get a list of files in a directory and then check their extensions to see if they are JPG, PDF, or other.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string directory = "C:\\";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("files.csv"))
        {
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
                writer.WriteLine("{0},{1}", file, extension);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When doing so how can I get that to show in a csv file? My goal is to have a csv file with a list of each file.

Comment: You can use the System.IO.File class to create a CSV file with the list of files and their extensions.

Comment: Awesome! When I use this as a method outside of the main void how can I call it in the main area?

Comment: You can call the method from the main area like this:

methodName();

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Matcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.filesystemglobbing.matcher?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) to traverse a folder structure using wild cards to getting specific file types and exclusions also.

Example method

```
public static async Task Demo(string parentFolder, string[] patterns, string[] excludePatterns, string fileName)
{

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    
    Matcher matcher = new();
    matcher.AddIncludePatterns(patterns);
    matcher.AddExcludePatterns(excludePatterns);

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {

        foreach (string file in matcher.GetResultsInFullPath(parentFolder))
        {
            builder.AppendLine(file);
        }
    });

    await File.WriteAllTextAsync("TODO", builder.ToString());

}
```

Example call, find all `png` and `pdf` files but exclude some specified in the exclude array which is explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.filesystemglobbing.matcher?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#remarks).

```
string[] include = { "**/*.png", "**/*.pdf" };
string[] exclude = { "**/*in*.png", "**/*or*.png" };
await GlobbingOperations.Demo(
    "Parent folder", 
    include, 
    exclude, 
    "Dump.txt");
```

When traversing files add any other logic to get specifics about a file and use that to add to the `builder` variable for writing to a file.